# How to create an add-on and share it with other people?

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

I have created a few macros with the help of this community the last week, but now I am going to be off work for some time, therefore I need to hand my work over but for that people will need access to my macros. I have created a custom tab for myself that contains all my macros and they only need to follow instructions and click on them in theory.

I however, had issues creating that add-in. I have created the .xlam file but even though people select and load it my macros won't appear, neither at the developer -> Macros tab, nor my tab will appear. The only way for them to run my macros if the add-in is loaded if they go into the visual basic window and run it from there, but I don't want them to do that as I want to protect that with a  password eventually.

If somebody has got a solution and willing to help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your tab in the Excel ribbon?  Are your users saving the file into the Excel start-up folder (Look at `Application.StartupPath` for path)?

Comment: Yes my tab is int eh excel ribbon. The code I have tried to create the add-on with is form microsoft's site but didn't work and I can't see any Application.StartupPath formula?

Comment: From the Visual Basic window; open the `Immediate Window` (Ctrl + G or *View* >> *Immediate Window*).  Type `? Application.StartupPath`.  Press enter.  Add-ins saved this in folder are automatically started when Excel opens.

Comment: Due to the company's policy we are only allowed to save the custom add-ins to the shared drive. I did what you've said and it's saying it's Appdata/Roaming/Microsoft/Ecvel/XLSTART, any idea how do I change this?

Comment: You can try [this, from Mircosoft](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Automatically-open-a-specific-workbook-or-template-when-you-start-Excel-be9cddc1-a148-4cbf-8f3b-779df08957a3) (not tested).  Alternatively; *File* >> *Options* >> *Add-ins* >> *Excel Add-ins* (manage drop-down) >> *Go* >> *Browse...* will allow you to install from a custom location.

Comment: And is that going to make my custom tab appear as well? I'll test it tomorrow if it works I'll let you know and please post it as an answer so I can upvote and mark it as the correct answer :).

Comment: Yes it should.  Posted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Into the Visual Basic window, you can import your .xlam file with Tools > References > Browse. Now, you should see your file into the Project Explorer of Visual Basic.
Hope this help !

Comment: We are able to see my add-in at the visual basic tab, but none of my stuff will appear elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of different ways you can install an Excel .xlam add-in.

**Method One**

Save the add-in Excel's start-up folder.  Any Excel files saved in this folder are automatically loaded when Excel starts.  To view the start-up path:

1. Open the Visual Basic window.
2. Open the Immediate Window (Ctrl + G or View >> Immediate Window).
3. Type `? Application.StartupPath`.

You can also [change the start-up path](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Automatically-open-a-specific-workbook-or-template-when-you-start-Excel-be9cddc1-a148-4cbf-8f3b-779df08957a3):

1. Click File >> Excel Options >> Advanced.
2. Under General, in the At Startup, open all files in box, type the full path of the folder that you want to use as the alternate startup folder.

**Method Two**

You can install the add-in directly:

1. Click File >> Options >> Add-ins
2. Pick `Excel Add-ins` from the manage drop-down (near the bottom of the screen).
3. Press Go >> Browse...
4. Navigate to the .xlam add-in you want to use.